Is my understanding about sufficient statistics correct?
Definition: a statistic $T(X)$ is sufficient for a parameter $\theta$ if the conditional distribution of the sample data $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ given $T(x)$ does not depend on $\theta$.
My question is: I already got the idea of sufficient statistic and through some search on StackExchange I also encounter some intuitive example that help me understand the concept. But there is one point that I have in my head that I'm not sure is right. Is my following understanding correct:
The conditional distribution of $(X_1,...,X_n)$ given $T(x)$ is calculated as $P_\theta(X_1 = x_1,...,X_n = x_n | T(X))$ Normally the measure P will depend on the parameter $\theta$, but since the statistic $T(X)$ has sufficient informations about $\theta$ so the measure P would not depend on the parameter $\theta$ anymore if given $T(X)$.
I would really appriciate for your response.

I think you are right. That's why $T$ is said to be sufficient: It contains everything that you need to know.
